# Q: How to improve performance with initializing maps with AutoMapper on ARM devices

Tags: c#, performance, automapper

We are currently using AutoMapper in client applications running cross-platform across Windows (UWP) and Android (Xamarin Native) using the latest release (7.0.1) running on ARM devices.

Our code currently creates 237 maps with the mapping expression as part of the Mapper.Initialize call. Some of these maps are quite complex, requiring additional ForMember, BeforeMap and AfterMap calls. Some of our models are also very large with many properties that need mapping.

After doing some initial investigation, we found that the entire Mapper.Initialize call can sometimes take around 12 seconds to complete (tested on Android and Windows devices on ARM processors). This unfortunately isn't ideal as we need the maps registered for when the application has loaded so initialize them during the extended splash screen.

Our application previously used ExpressMapper which with the same number of maps would enter into the application within 8 seconds. We are now looking from start-up to app ready being 20+ seconds with AutoMapper. The reason for changing is that we believe AutoMapper to support .NET Native which is required for submission to the Windows Store, where ExpressMapper did not.

Having done some further testing, we can confirm that the time isn't spend during the CreateMap calls as part of the MapperConfigurationExpression but are in the Initialize call itself.

Some further research into AutoMapper functions looked like we might be able to leverage the [inline mapping function](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Inline-Mapping.html), however we found that a lot of our maps also have many inherited objects that we have custom CreateMap calls for.

We had noticed that AutoMapper has a mechanism for Profiles but were unsure based on the documentation as to whether this is a way of improving the Initialize function or whether it is just a container for maps and nothing else.

The questions I have around performance are:

1. Has anyone found ways of improving the speed of the Initialize method for a large number of maps?
2. If not, is there something that I've potentially missed to improve the way I'm creating maps in order to speed up the Initialize method?

Comment: You'll have to profile it and find out where exactly that time is spent so we can fix it. Or make a repro and we'll take it from there. But this is new to me :)

Comment: Working on producing a sample with the issue in. I've noticed I can make a single CreateMap call and this alone takes 5 seconds to initialize on an ARM device

Comment: Then I guess this is specific to ARM-s and that would explain why didn't see anything like that on Wintel.

Comment: Yeah, running the app on a Windows PC with Intel is less than a second. It appears all of the time is within the MapperConfiguration constructor, particularly with the Seal method.

Comment: Seal goes over everything and generates all the needed expressions trees. But as you can see, it's fast enough on Wintel, so the question remains, what _exactly_ is slow on ARM.